# MouseLeftButtonUp event not firing in WPF window on some computers

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

FloatView.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Floai.Pages.FloatView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Floai" Height="30" Width="80"
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Topmost="True" >

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="../Styles/Themes/Light.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="canvas" >
        <Border x:Name="border" CornerRadius="5" Background="{DynamicResource btn_main_bg_brush}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="Border_MouseLeftButtonUp" 
                MouseLeave="border_MouseLeave" MouseEnter="border_MouseEnter">
            <Label Content="@Floai" FontSize="16" Foreground="{DynamicResource btn_main_fg_brush}" Width="80" 
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

FloatView.xaml.cs

```
        private Point _previousWindowPosition;

        private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _previousWindowPosition = new Point(Left, Top);
            DragMove();
        }


        private void Border_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_previousWindowPosition == new Point(Left, Top))
            {
                ShowWindow();
            }
        }
```

I want to implement a function where clicking on this floating window can open a new window, and holding down and moving the mouse can drag this floating window.However, I have encountered some problems:

The code runs normally on my computer. I tried it on multiple laptops, three of which can run it correctly. However, on the other three laptops, it cannot run properly when using an external mouse, but works fine with the touchpad.
After debugging, I found the following issue: The `MouseLeftButtonDown` event can be triggered, but the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event cannot be triggered.

After removing the `MouseLeftButtonDown` event and running the program again, the `MouseLeftButtonUp` event can be triggered properly.
What can I do to make both events trigger, or achieve the same functionality in another way?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this feature using another approach, and here is the code:

```
private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled= true;
    Point beforeDragMovePosition = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);
    if (e.LeftButton== MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        this.DragMove();
    }
    Point afterDragMovePosition = new Point(this.Left, this.Top);
    if (beforeDragMovePosition == afterDragMovePosition)
    {
        ShowWindow();
    }
}
```